# Relative Permittivity in a "Good Conductor"

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, conductors

I have a question in which I need to show that sea water is effectively a "good conductor", when considering the propagation of radio waves of frequency $< 10^9$. We're given that the conductivity of sea water is around $5 Sm^{-1}$ and has a refractive index of around $9$.

It is my understanding that in order to show that the sea water is a "good conductor", you would need to show that: $\sigma>>\omega\epsilon_r\epsilon_0$

$\sigma, \omega, \epsilon_0$ are trivial but I am not sure how you would get a value of $\epsilon_r$.

**Edit:**
I managed to solve the problem using Gilbert's help.

Here's my proof:

As,
$${v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}},$$
$$v=\frac{c}{n},$$
$$\mu_r=1,$$
$$\implies v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}}=\frac{c}{n},$$

$$\implies \mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0=\frac{n^2}{c^2},$$

$$\implies \mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0=\frac{n^2}{c^2},$$

$$\implies \epsilon_r=\frac{n^2}{c^2\mu_0\epsilon_0},$$

As $\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{\mu_0c^2}$,

$$\implies \epsilon_r=n^2$$

Comment: P.66 of your notes?

Comment: I see this now... I also enjoyed the final problem of your sheet. After I had finished it, I applied its concepts to radio waves and electrical wiring - which is in itself, an interesting area. With a bit of digging in the general area I came across [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122315/should-a-faraday-cage-block-a-radios-signal).
I was wondering if you would make an appearance with this question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-magnetic materials, $n=\sqrt{\epsilon_r}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gilbet, do you have some resource in which I can read on this?

Comment: @HomelessSandwich check out Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation. The refractive index is defined by the speed of light in a medium v=c/n. Then from Maxwell’s equations, you can see that the speed of propagation of electromagnetic radiation is 1/(\epsilon\mu).

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to prove what you are saying with the following.
$v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$, $v=\frac{c}{n}$ and as $\mu_r=1$, 
$\implies v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}}=\frac{c}{n}$ ,
$\implies \mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0=\frac{n^2}{c^2}$,
$\implies \mu_0\epsilon_r\epsilon_0=\frac{n^2}{c^2}$,
$\implies \epsilon_r=\frac{n^2}{c^2\mu_0\epsilon_0}$,
As $\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{\mu_0c^2}$,
$\implies \epsilon_r=n^2$

Comment: @HomelessSandwich that’s right! I also have a typo in my above comment: it’s missing the \sqrt.